# Mysql store incorrect encoded char

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

i'm trying to insert accented char into mysql table with encoding `utf8_general_ci`.

This is a simple string that i'm trying to insert:

```
Porto leça da palmeira
```

To insert that string i'm using php in this way:

```
$string = "Porto leça da palmeira";
$id     = "xxxx";
$sql    = "INSERT INTO city_translates (id,city) VALUES ('$id','$string')";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host.....");  
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->query($sql);
```

When i try when to access from `MysqlWorkBench` that string, it has been stored in this way:

```
Porto - Le?Ãa da Palmeira
```

if i try to use `utf8_encode` such as:

```
$string = utf8_encode($string);
```

it will be stored in this way:

```
Porto - Le?ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂŸa da Palmeira
```

How can i solve?
What could be my error?

Thanks!

Comment: try mysql_escape_string()

Comment: Use `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass,
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));` and changing the variables to your own. It should work. You can also use `$dbh->exec("set names utf8");`

Comment: @napster3world OP is using PDO. Those two APIs do not mix.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you very much!!! using charset into PDO constructor fixed the problem! :) THANKS! :D

Comment: Might I also suggest that you use placeholders instead of variables. [**See PDO prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for more information on those. Even though you are using PDO, you are still open to SQL injection, strangely enough.

Comment: @JackTurky: Please, never ever use `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` unless you are absolutely positively sure that what you try to encode is in latin1 aka ISO-8859-1. If you haven't looked closely those two functions are part of the XML Parser functions. They have been conveniently put there by some fool. If you have to deal with charset conversion use appropriate tools like e.g. the `iconv` extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(As suggested I put my comment as an answer)

Use

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

and changing the variables to your own.

You can also use `$dbh->exec("set names utf8");`

As per http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

---

Might I also suggest that you use placeholders instead of variables. [**See PDO prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) for more information on those. Even though you are using [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo), you are still open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/), *strangely enough.*

Comment: @Darren Oh, you saw that, did ya Darren? Yeah, let's just say that I'm helping out for a very few deserving ones who are faced with more complex problems, than mere "quotes around tables and columns". I give out more comments than answers lol

Comment: @Darren Yeah, me too. But just not as many "answers". There are too many low-quality questions lately, where all they do is open up cans of worms, or aggravation, and/or no results because the person at the other end has chosen the wrong career move.

Comment: Oh couldn't agree with you more on that. The amount of recent "comment answers" is blowing my mind aswell!

Comment: @Darren I have also noticed a rather significant decrease lately in (PHP/SQL) questions though. I guess the wind must've blown through some of their ears, as to how things are run around here.